# Is there a way to force a Hylotl Ruined Castle to appear on a planet?

Tags: starbound

Looking on the [wiki](https://starbounder.org/Hylotl_Ruined_Castle) a Hylotl Ruined Castle can appear on any planet with the exception for moons, any ocean worlds (including magma, arctic, and toxic) or garden planets.

I like Hylotl Ruined Castles because they have that Japanese feel to them but while in my current game i made my base from one, the problem is that this one was in the starting solar system so it wasn't hard for me to find and i fear that if i start a new game i wont find another one so easily.

So is there a way to force a Hylotl Ruined Castle to appear on a planet?

Answer (score 1):

Use the command /placedungeon and add the name e.g evilfortres for a glitchcastle, in this case the command would be /placedungeon hylotlruinedcastle.Bear in mind that the generation is random so dont expect a certain castle on the first one.